# Different behavior of Sharepoint controls on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

Some Sharepoint controls sadly behave different **on postback**:
I started with:

```
<SharePointWebControls:NoteField id="3" FieldName="MultiText" runat="server" />
<PublishingWebControls:RichLinkField id="4" FieldName="Link" runat="server" />
```

These controls render &nbsp for blank fields. That lead to unwanted whitespace on postback.
After some research I found a solution like
suggested [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2007/02/21/using-field-value-controls-and-edit-mode-panels-to-tweak-your-page-rendering.aspx) :

```
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat=server id="EditModePanelView" PageDisplayMode="Display" SuppressTag="true">
   <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue id="3" FieldName="MultiText" runat="server"/>
   <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue id="4" FieldName="Link" runat="server" />
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>

<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" id="EditModePanelEdit">
   <SharePointWebControls:NoteField id="7" FieldName="MultiText" runat="server" />
   <PublishingWebControls:RichLinkField id="8" FieldName="Link" runat="server" />
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

...no &nbsp in blank fields anymore:

- In Edit-Mode the specific WebControls are used.
- In display mode of the page, there is used [SharepointWebControls:FieldValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.fieldvalue.aspx) to simply render the content.

Now a new problem occured: 
Any line breaks (rendered as br-Tags) that are entered in edit mode for a NoteField are lost, when rendered as SharePointWebControls:FieldValue. Is there any way to render the html of the NoteField as is in display mode? So that the breaks don't get lost and there are no additional non-breaking spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with overwriting the Sharepoint Controls like suggested [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2007/03/29/how-to-overcome-glitches-with-the-standard-field-controls-shipped-with-moss-2007.aspx):

I had to overwrite [NoteField#RenderFieldForDisplay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.notefield.renderfieldfordisplay.aspx) like this, so that NoteField behaves the same on postback and on GET:

```
protected override void RenderFieldForDisplay(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
  TextWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  base.RenderFieldForDisplay(new HtmlTextWriter(writer));
  string x=  writer.ToString();
  string y= "&#160;";
  string z= "<br/>";
  x= x.Equals(y) ? x.Replace(y, string.Empty) : x.Replace(" ", y).Replace("\r\n", z).Replace("\n", z).Replace("\r", z);
  output.Write(x);
}
```

This works but it sucks. I still don't get it why sharepoint controls behave different on postback and replace e.g. br-Tags with line breaks...